# Grails binary plugin - No signature of method isDirty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

Tags: grails, groovy

Our project is devided into a main project and a domain plugin. Main project is on grails 2.3.7 and domain plugin is on 2.2.3
Domain plugin is packaged as binary and used in Main project.

However Main project (2.3.7) complains about Missing method isDirty(). (If domain plugin is used as inline, it resolves the issue) 
The other project which is on grails 2.2.3 has no issues with binary domain plugin.

So, what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graeme replied

> You can't do this. You need to compile the plugin with 2.3.7 as you are missing some key AST transforms if you don't